# Linq Include and Where conditions on Parent-child relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

This is my scenerio:

I have model of `Company`:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id      { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Product>  Products  { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

and API endpoint that looks like this:

```
    //GET: api/company/Profile?id=stringid
    [Route("Profile")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Company))]
    public IHttpActionResult<Company> GetEmployeeCompany(string userId)
    {
         var company = db.Companies
                 .Include(p => p.Products)
                 .Where(u => u.Employees.userId == userId);

         return Ok(company)

        //that return dont work ofc, but i just want to show what im talking about
    }
```

My question is, how to find `Company` with his products, that employee is employed? Employee have unique userId that is string. I pass that string by endpoit in api call

**EDIT**

`Employee` class

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company         Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User    { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you actually do your search by profile ID, you may want to load an employee by profile ID and include its company and the company's products:

```
var employee = db.Employees
    .Include(e => e.Company.Products)
    .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == userId);

return employee.Company.Products; // to return company's products
return employee.Company; // to return company, will contain all products
```

It should work.

Comment: I get an error, that `Company` does not contain a defition of `Select`

Comment: And is it possible, to get `Company` property on return instead of `Employee`?

Comment: @michasaucer Oh, sure, sorry, could you please check the updated answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: I make an edit to my post, i changed return type, sorry for problems

Comment: @michasaucer I am not sure what you mean by the second question, but it is natural to search it in `db.Employees`, because you actually search by Employee's ID, not company's.

Comment: So i need to deal with Employee with related company object in my frontend?

Comment: @michasaucer What exactly are you trying to achieve? You can include `Products` and return `employee.Company` itself, if you want your front-end to receive a company with all its products :) See the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to include an inner check of whether there is `Any` employee within the `Company` with the given `userId`:

```
//GET: api/company/Profile?id=stringid
[Route("Profile")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Company))]
public IHttpActionResult<Company> GetEmployeeCompany(string userId)
{
    var company = db.Companies
             .Include(p => p.Products)
             .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Employees.Any(e => e.UserId == userId));

     if (company == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }

     return Ok(company);
}
```